# Why there is 2 equals signs ia an if statement on python

Tags: python

`if op == "+": print(num1 + num2)`

Why it's used two equal signs on this if statment instead of only one?

Comment: one `=` is for assignment ... like in `x =  5` meaning put the value `5` to variable `x` ... two  `==` means equality

Comment: assignment vs Boolean operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

== is a comparison operator
You can use == to see whether any two items as long they are the same type are equivalent:

```
a = 2
if a == 2: # Compares whether a is equal to 2. this is true.
    print(a)
```

When using ==, if the two items are the same, it will return True. Otherwise, it will return False.

---

And with your code,

```
if op == "+": print(num1 + num2)
```

Means if the op variable is same as the "+", print the result of num1 + num2

Comment: You won't get an error for any of those; `==` silently returns `False` for mismatched types (and `!=` silently returns `True`). The rich comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`) will raise `TypeError`, but `==`/`!=` won't.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh, right. my bad. edited to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

For the same reason many languages do so; because `=` is already being used for assignment. `op = "+"` is a request to assign the string to `op`; `op == "+"` is asking if `op` already contains an equivalent string.

Python goes a step further and forbids assignment via `=` as an expression, so typos using `=` where `==` was intended don't accidentally perform assignment (a problem in many C-like languages) and evaluate the assigned value for "truthiness" (`if op = "+":` will error, rather than silently misbehaving), though recent versions of Python include a walrus operator (`:=`) for when this is a desired behavior (`:=` being harder to accidentally type than simply omitting one `=`).

Answer (score 0):

The two equal signs are to denote that the the variable is exactly equal to the comparator for example if we say in simple words.

The thing I'm comparing is exactly equal to the thing that I want, for example

```
1 == 1 # This means that the number one is exactly equal to the number one.
```

And in your case.

```
op == "+"  # Whatever the op is if it's a "+" sign do something with it.
```